# Image set as background of toggle button is stretched android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Toggle Button as:

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tv_pmpSwitch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            />
```

And my toggle_view drawable is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_list_action"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_grid_action"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

I don't understand why the image in background is stretched ?? I've tried various size images.

Comment: what is the weightSum of your linear layout holding the togglebutton?

Comment: weightsum is 1 and there are two other text views of weight 0.45 each respectively

Comment: try reducing the weight of your ToggleButton further to .05 or less and keep all other weights

Comment: Its not working Ansal Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out a few things I found what was wrong:

 The weightSum was the culprit and the assigned weight was stretching the image.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_pmpSwitch"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_list"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Putting the whole code inside a LL parent did the trick

Answer (score 11):

You can simply set in the xml layout file:

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

The image will not stretch anymore

Answer (score 8):

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tv_pmpSwitch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_view"                
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
```

Try this on your code and adjust only layout height parameter!

**EDIT**

The way to get a non stretched image is using a bitmap and not a drawable.
use following as your xml as your background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_list_action"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_grid_action"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: that seems to work. Just tell me two things and I'll accept it as answer. First: will this fixed dp height create issues with change in device size & Second: What was issue with wrap content if it already has weight sum assigned? thanks

Comment: see the answer now, thanks for the help but that was the issue

Comment: The key here seems to be the `gravity` attribute of `bitmap`, without it the image is still stretched. You can still put the item in a selector instead of a layer list.